# AndEngine accelerometer randomly fails?

Tags: java, android, andengine, accelerometer

I am working on an app, and right now there is a bug that occurs randomly. Sometimes when I try to load a scene that extends onSensorChangeListener the app will crash. It took me forever to get the log cat (because the bug occurs at random) and I don't understand what it is saying:

```
01-02 12:17:10.942: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(24294): QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
01-02 12:17:11.102: E/MediaPlayer(24294): Should have subtitle controller already set
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/SensorManager(24294): Exception dispatching input event.
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294): Process: com.magnusworks.justtic_tac_toe, PID: 24294
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294):    at com.magnusworks.justtic_tac_toe.MainGameScene.onSensorChanged(MainGameScene.java:250)
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294):    at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:474)
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5678)
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
01-02 12:17:15.352: E/AndroidRuntime(24294):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As for the scene, it looks like this (And yes, the class extends the onClickListener):

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        switch(event.sensor.getType()){
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(-event.values[0] * 10, event.values[1] * 10);
            physicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);
            Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I keep getting this error?

EDIT:

```
@Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

This is what is currently at line 250 of mainGameScene, However I have made some changes to the code so i'm not entirely sure if this is what logcat was referencing. I have been trying to get the crash again so I can see the new logcat, however the crash is always random so its impossible to force :/

Comment: What is at line 250 in MainGameScene?

Comment: @Override
 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

Comment: There's null pointer exception in the onSensorChanged function, where is it? it is written in line 250 , but it isn't the line u wrote to me